# Is there a way to send a <li> element to jquery function?

Tags: jquery, html, list, pug

I do not know if this problem is possible to solve, but I want to send the content in a li-element to a jquery function. I have written the view code in pug.

I'm creating a chat function where the user should be able to login and connect with socket.io. The users are saved and listed in a view (To keep it short). The view is written in pug. I want to be able to click on one of the list items, send the user name (the list value) to a jquery function to later on send it to my server to create a chat room. Is there a way to make this happen?

View:

```
#users
      br
      h1 Inloggade användare
      br
      ul.list-group#userlist
        each user, i in users
          li.list-group-item
            p(value=user)= user
```

jquery function:

```
  $('#userlist').on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('chat request', "THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SEND THE USER NAME FROM THE LIST");
  });
``
```

Comment: `#userlist` would be the ul.  `#userlist li` would be each of the lis.  If you bind your click event listener to that, it's as simple as `e.target.innerText` to get the displayed text of the li.

Comment: are you using pug in the project? because it compiles to: https://codepen.io/isethi/pen/pmjGOx

Comment: Thank you Taplar! It works if i write:   $('#userlist').on( "click", function(e) {
    socket.emit('chat request', e.target.innerText);
  }); Not with #userlist li , wonder why? Yes, i'm using pug !